# How to organize my git repository with dependencies?

Tags: python, git, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using a self-hosted GitLab instance with several Python projects. All of these projects now have a pipeline which execute several Py linters and static analyzers. The gitlab runners have `python3` installed, including the required packages/linters. So the runners sinply execute:

```
$ python3 -m pylint project_foo
$ python3 -m pylint project_bar
```

If I ever want to use another linter version I would need to "update" all projects, since there is only a system wide linter installed. I have now two options.

1. I submit all modules required by the pipeline also to the repo
2. I use Python virtual environments
3. Another idea?

I am looking for someone who can share some experiences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using **container-based executors**, i.e. Docker or Kubernetes ones: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/README.html

Then in each job of your pipeline you choose the right Docker image for the job.
It gives you the flexibility to use any python version, or indeed any image from millions at Docker Hub.

You pay the price of installing your dependencies or tools each job run on top of official image - some build time increase.

```
run_script:
  image: python:3
  script:
    - pip3 install pipenv
    - pipenv install
    - pipenv run ./my_beautiful_script.py
```

You can create a custom image with your specific tools\configs\prerequisites\dependencies\environment and use it, but I prefer not too. As another benefit of such approach - you also test the installation of those, which is a best practice in Continuous Delivery.

With regards to **python linters** - I chose to use several of them at the same time, as they cover different aspects of quality, and I mostly run them through [pre-commit hooks](https://pre-commit.com/), which I also execute in the GitLab CI in case a developer forgets to install hooks locally.

Example of stripped down `.pre-commit-config.yaml`:

```
repos:
- repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
  rev: v2.5.0
  hooks:
    - id: check-yaml

- repo: https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8
  rev: 3.7.9
  hooks:
    - id: flake8

- repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-autopep8
  rev: v1.5
  hooks:
    - id: autopep8
      args: [--diff]

- repo: https://github.com/asottile/pyupgrade
  rev: v2.1.0
  hooks:
    - id: pyupgrade
```

and `.gitlab-ci.yml` that runs pre-commit as well as other python linters:

```
python-lint:
  image: python:3
  script:
    - pip3 -q install pre-commit pycodestyle pylint

    - pre-commit run -a

    - pycodestyle --version
    - pycodestyle --verbose --show-source *.py

    - pylint --version
    - find . -name "*.py" -print0 | xargs -0 pylint
```

See full files in the template project I made to use for all python-related code: https://gitlab.com/softmill/template-projects/python

Comment: Thank you very much! Thats exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad it helped!